# the confirmation alert working in the browser, but not working in cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, alert

everyone, I'm just developing a intro video using jquerymobile for a cordova app, i did a alert information to ask user if they want to play the intro video, if yes, the popup window open and play the video, if no, just show the index page, below is my code, could some one help me, any suggestion will be really appreciate.

```
<body>
     <script>
                $(document).on("pageshow", function(){
                    if (confirm("Do you want to play intro video?") == true)                          {
                   $("#introVideo").popup("open");
                   var vid=document.getElementById("fin");
                    vid.play();
                    } else {                      
                         //
                     }
                   });
        </script>   
</body>
```

it works in the browser,but when i build it with cordova and install into my Android phone, it doesn't work.

Comment: What OS are you running cordova?

Comment: use the dialogs plugin and read the doc to see how to use the confirm

Comment: Thanks very much, that worked.Helen